# Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I am trying to Sync my project after adding Firebase Gradle Dependency Line:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0
```

for realtime database, I am getting this error:

```
Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0]
```

Can you help me how to resolve this error?

Comment: You should place that line in `android/app/build.gradle` not in `android/build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled "compile" in the dependency block in your Module:app build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'  // NOT complie
    ...
}
```